# Referencing an external drive in PHP

Tags: php, wamp

Okay, so i am trying to start hosting my own file sharing site, i currently am using WAMP server to have server properties with apache, PHP, mysql, etc. I have my root folder located in a 2TB hard drive and i would like to list folders/files in another hard drive. But when i use the dir function it does not link to the actual files it just lists them. I would like to allow people to download the files in my HDD to there client computers. Any ideas on how to work this out and link to the actual files?

Comment: Can you show a code example and what it outputs?

Comment: You can create a junction point inside your webroot to that drive's directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't link to files that are not in your website directly.

What you can do is have all the links point to a download script that takes a parameter which points to the file.  That script can then make it work in memory.

Here's an example I found on the web here:
http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download

```
// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path2file/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
$fullPath = $path . $_GET['download_file'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) 
{
    $fsize      = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext        = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    switch ($ext) 
    {
        case "pdf":
            header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
            break;

        default:
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
            break;
    }

    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly

    while(!feof($fd)) 
    {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;

// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
```

Comment: i made a new PHP page and placed it in my root folder but when i open it it gives me 3 errors, i used the exact code you gave me with some minor altercations to the file path but it still wont work. my root directory is: F:/wamp/www/nfs/. I am trying to reference or download files from another drive located with the letter P:/. It is saying that my errors are on line 12, 14, and 42.

Comment: here is a pic of the errors i get while testing the code you provided: 
[img]http://bayimg.com/dAKNHAaDJ[img]

Comment: You're going to have to start debugging.  The first error is in reference to "Undefined index: download_file".  That means that the get at the top doesn't have a parameter called download_file.  The link at the bottom of the code snippet shows how to construct the links so that the $_GET array will have a key of download_file.

Answer (score 0):

In linux i would create a symbolic link from the external hard drive into you webroot folder, but under windows it looks like you need to create a junction directory.

Have a read of this, it explains how to create it.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/

Your directory structure should end up looking like this

```
webroot
|- php files
|- externalfiles (dir junction to ext hard drive)
   |- sharedfile1 
   |- sharedfile2
```